# Why does one function works, but the other does not?

Tags: javascript, display

This one works, it shows the table:
When I put .style.display = "tablerow", the function works

```
var getMain = document.getElementById("main").style.display = "table-row";
var getLocalStorage = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('tableFill');
for (i = 0; i < getLocalStorage.lenght; i++) {
    if (getLocalStorage[i]){


       getMain;
```

But when I put it in in the for loop it doesn't work anymore, but I also get no error at all in the console...

```
var getMain = document.getElementById("main");
var getLocalStorage = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('tableFill');
for (i = 0; i < getLocalStorage.lenght; i++) {
    if (getLocalStorage[i]){


       getMain.style.display = "table-row";
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.hasOwnProperty('tableFill')` returns true or false. Does not have any length so you won't get into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.hasOwnProperty('tableFill')` returns a boolean to check if the property exists or not. It does not have data to make a loop out of it